# Error passing arguments from Java to Python

Tags: java, python, getopt

I'm calling on some Python modules from Java. The module is using numpy, so I'm using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to call Python. In Java I am doing something like this:

```
File python = new File("/usr/bin/python2.7");
File script = new File("/opt/my_custom_script.py");
String[] cmdArray = new String[] { python.toString(), script.toString(),
    "-i infile.txt", "-o outfile.txt" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
p.waitFor();
if (p.exitValue() != 0) {
    throw new Exception(scriptName + " failed with exit code " + p.exitValue());
}
```

And in Python I've gotten thus far:

```
def main(argv):
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "i:o:")
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print(err)
        sys.exit(128) # made up number so I know when this happens

    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Every time I run this I keep on getting the error number I made up, and my Python script runs no further. Calling on Python directly (in bash) gives me no problems.

Where is my disconnect? How would I go about troubleshooting/debugging this?

Comment: What is `print(err)` printing?

Comment: The sys.edit(128) line really jars me.  I know it's for debugging, but passing a variable is really a good idea.  Magic numbers only result in pain.

Comment: I think your arguments need to be separate elements in the array: eg. `"-i infile.txt"` -> `"-i", "infile.txt"`

Comment: Judging by the typo in the code (`Sting[]`) this not the actual code you're running. Please post that.

Comment: @kindall he also forgot a semicolon: new Sting[] { python.toString(), script.toString(),
    "-i infile.txt", "-o outfile.txt" }

Comment: You should try to use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead, 'Runtime.exec()' is not the best way to call back to the operating system any more.

Comment: Out of votes but agree with @AdamSpurgin. The command line "-i infile.txt -o outfile.txt" is four arguments, not two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are passing two options two the script rather than the four that getopt expects. That is, `-i infile.txt` is treated as one option, not, as getopt expects, the two options `-i` and `infile.txt`, and the same thing is happening to `-o outfile.txt`. You can fix this by replacing the line:

```
String[] cmdArray = new String[] { python.toString(), script.toString(), "-i infile.txt", "-o outfile.txt" };
```

with this line:

```
String[] cmdArray = new String[] { python.toString(), script.toString(), "-i", "infile.txt", "-o", "outfile.txt" };
```

Notice that now `-i` and `infile.txt` are now separate array elements, as are `-o` and `-outfile.txt`.